# Maven : Usage of dependency tag inside pom.xml files incase of different modules

Tags: maven-2

I am working on a maven Application.
We have got 5 Modules, so there are a total of 6 pom.xml files as part of our Application.

```
<module>myware</module>
<module>XMLModule</module>
<module>Business</module>
<module>Tests</module>
<module>bayers</module>
```

For all these modules , i have mentioned the relative-path tag to refer to the parent pom.xml file.

If the same jar file is required by many modules, do we need to mention this inside every pom.xml file??

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you depend on several common libraries it would be possible to create another
module that lists these as dependencies, and depend on this module to pull them
in transitively. This is however not a best practice with maven, it is
recommended to list your dependencies explicitly and not rely on transitive
dependencies. See for example this [note on dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

You can however simplify the dependency section a bit by using a
`dependencyManagement` element in your parent pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <!-- type and scope omitted since they use the default values -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This allows to declare the version in just one place, you can then omit the `version` element in the `dependencies` section of your modules.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Also note that dependencies are transient. So if Tests depends on Business, then it will get all compile/runtime dependencies of Business, too.